# How to reference a collection in a formula

Tags: excel, vba

All I want to do is reference a collection in a formula. Like

Assume I already know how to make collections and arrays and have done so in my macro, Collection is literally a collection with only 1 column, and Textstring is an array vector.

```
'For every value of i in Textstring, I want to count the occurrence of that value in all the values of 'Collection'
For i = 1 to Whatever 
    =COUNTIF(Collection, """ & TextString(i) & """)
Next i
```

What I want to know is how to make aforementioned code work.

It should work like a normal countif:

```
'ie: "=COUNTIF('Sheet1'!A1:A10, ""blah"")"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't with `COUNTIF`, if you have a look at the arguments to the function, it expects a **Range** object.

[image]

The only suggestion I have is to do something like the below, i.e. write it out to a worksheet and then use that range as a parameter to your function ...

```
Public Sub CollectionToRange()
    Dim objCollection As New Collection, i As Long

    For i = 1 To 10
        objCollection.Add i
    Next

    ' Convert the collection to a range.
    For i = 1 To objCollection.Count
        Sheet1.Cells(i, 1) = objCollection.Item(i)
    Next

    ' Pass the range into the worksheet function.
    Debug.Print "CountIf Result = " & WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheet1.Range("A1:A" & objCollection.Count), ">3")

    ' Perform a clean up if required.
End Sub
```

[image]

Not sure if that helps or not.

Comment: If that’s the case, how would you do it? Especially for multiple if statements.

Comment: Well ... depending on how many you have to do, probably somewhat painfully.  How many properties in your collection do you want to do it for?  How many we talkin'?  You could always do it in the old fashioned way using a FOR loop.  You have that anyway when writing it out to the sheet.  I tend to think it's better to use the in built function though, more likely to work seamlessly.

Comment: okay then. How do you reference all the items in a collection in say: application.count(collection)

Comment: If you're asking what I think you're asking then getting the count of the collection is just as in my example, objCollection.Count ... is that what you mean?

Comment: Something more like:  for i = 1 to blah, for j = 1 to whatever, for k = 1 to don’tcare                   “=COUNTIFS(Coll1, Array1(k,i), Coll2, Array2(j))          Next k, next j, next i

Comment: @EdwardAzar it’s the same thing, if you have multiple properties in your collection object, you need to write them all out to a range and use that range in the COUNTIFS function. It’s no different to doing it on the worksheet. Make sense?